# rsyslog: parse nginx access log and send it via omhttp to backend

Tags: nginx, rsyslog

I need to read nginx access_log file and send data to http backend when line contents 'some expression'.
It is a part of task to billing downloaded files via nginx `access_log`.

---

Nginx stores log to `/var/log/nginx/access.log`
In download format:

```
log_format download '{ "remote_addr": "$remote_addr", "time": "$time_local", "request": "$request", "traffic": $body_bytes_sent, "x_forwarded_for": "$http_x_forwarded_for" }';
```

Rsyslog watch this file (`/etc/rsyslog.conf`).

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10") 
input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/nginx/access.log"
      Tag="nginx-access"
      Severity="info"
      Facility="local3")
```

I need help with rsyslog omhttp module. How to configure it for:

- send only new lines when `:msg, contains, "expression"`
- send new line of access log to: POST http://localhost/rsyslog_backend

Comment: i use omhttp to send data via HTTp from rsyslog, but don't know how to configure it

Answer (score 0):

Right answer is using `syslog-ng` instead of `syslog`

Part of a configruration that do this job:

```
destination d_http {
  http(
    url("http://127.0.0.1/api/billing")
    method("POST")
    body("$(format-json message=$MESSAGE)")
  );
};

log {
  source(s_src);
  filter { program("nginx") and message("download\/ogg") };
  destination(d_http);
};
```

In a Rails some monkey patch needed:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.parse(request.raw_post)['message'])['request'] => "POST /api/subscriptions/downloads/billing HTTP/1.0"
```

Comment: '[the] right answer'?  How is that anything more than a "if A is giving you trouble, switch to B because... reasons"?